# Custom Parsing of Underscore Templates

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've written a function which takes a string, and returns information from a backbone model.  Rather than just pull straight properties from the model, though, it uses properties to form more complex data - for example, date parsing, or getting the correct icon to use for a certain type of object -

```
// returns a parsed date modified with format MM/DD/YYYY
parseString("dateProperty:MM/DD/YYYY:dateModified");
// returns the HTML needed to display an icon based on the model type.
parseString("icon:type");
```

Right now I'm calling my parse function from within the template itself -

```
<div>Date modified <%= parseString("dateProperty:MM/DD/YYYY:" + dateModified) %></div>
```

but **I'd love to be able to apply my parse function automatically to each value** instead of just shoving my Backbone model in and applying the properties directly.

Essentially, I'd like to be able to do this with my templates -

```
<div>Date modified <%= dateProperty:MM/DD/YYYY:dateModified %></div>
```

And send `dateProperty:MM/DD/YYYY:dateModified` off to `parseString`.

This is part of a rather large Backbone setup, and the `parseString` function is used throughout the JSON I use to build my models and collections; I'd like it if the behavior of strings in the templates were the same.

Comment: @muistooshort ha, sorry, `model.toJSON()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want that syntax, I think your best bet is to "copy" the `_.template` code out of underscore, and add support for your custom syntax in there.

If you had a syntax that is more amenable to JavaScript like a function call

```
<%= z$("dateProperty:MM/DD/YYYY:dateModified") %>
```

There would be a few other options (global, mixing in an object in the template `with` statement, etc). As it stands, you pretty much have to implement it yourself.

Or you could adopt a more featureful templating language.

Comment: This is pretty much inline with what I thought was going to happen.  Ah well.  Thanks!